# How to place a 3D object above the other one using Unity in AR?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on an AR-based project in Unity using Vuforia.

Is there a way to place a 3D object above another 3D object?

For e.g. I have placed a table above which I have to place something else like a flower vase or a cube over an already spawned cube. How to achieve this?

Because as far as I know, Unity is detecting only floor surface and if I try to place the flower vase over the already kept table, it is placing it under the table overlapping the existing 3D object.

I believe that the PerformHitTest in the PlaceFinderBehaviour script needs to be modified to return the object surface during a Hittest. How do I do approach this? the script is not having modify access in Unity.